# Why can't I round-trip an image using PyPNG?

Tags: python, pypng

This seems fairly simple:

```
import png
rdr = png.Reader(filename='help.png')
width, height, pixels, metadata = rdr.read()
with open('help-new.png', 'w') as outfile:
    png.Writer(**metadata).write(outfile, pixels)
```

However, I can't open my new image because the file "appears to be damaged, corrupted, or too large".  If I try to load the result back into PyPNG, I get this:

```
FormatError: FormatError: PNG file has invalid signature.
```

Additional info:  The metadata looks like this:

```
'bitdepth': 8, 'interlace': 0, 'planes': 1,
'greyscale': False, 'alpha': False, 'size': (18, 18)
```

The first palette entry is (0, 0, 0, 0), while the others are all of the form (255, 255, 255, A) where A is between 0 and 255.  The source file is 718 bytes, result file is 748 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the output file in binary mode:

```
open('help-new.png', 'wb') as outfile:
                       ^
                       |
                  that's it,
                  right there
```

Otherwise the I/O layer might do newline translation which you never want for binary files.

Comment: D'oh! Once again, the first person to look over my shoulder immediately sees the mistake. :-)